# Making use of a gemstone island?

Tags: dragonvale

I have a level 14 park with a new but empty Gemstone island.  What's a reasonable path to making use of that island?  There's about 750,000 dragon cash available. So far it seems every gem dragon can only be bred from dragons that themselves are rare, and it looks like a slog.

Comment: The epic breeding island is costs gems, not gold. So you could not have bought the epic breeding island with gold.

Comment: Now there is a gemstone habitat so the gemstone island isn't as necessary.